# Filter and Combine Stock Symbols With Their Price (Google Spreadsheets)

Tags: filter, google-sheets

I'm having a couple of issues using the filter function in google sheets on a sorted column.

Columns A and B contain the source information that needs to be modified.

Column D uses the function `=arrayformula(A1:A10&", "&B1:B10)` to combine A and B.

Column F uses the function `=sort(D1:D10, regexextract(to_text(D1:D10),"\d+")*1,true)` to sort the data from least to greatest and keep the symbols paired with their price.

Now what I want to do is look through the entire F column for prices that are greater than $4 and less than $20.

The goal is to keep the symbols paired with their prices so I would end up with a column that has only prices between $4 and $20

```
=filter(F1:F10, F1:F10 > 4, F1:F10 < 20)
```

[image: here's a picture of my spreadsheet]

Comment: The column F contains strings; what is F1:F10 > 4 supposed to mean? Also, I don't see the logic of your `sort` formula: the second argument of `sort` is the column number by which to sort (which is moot here since the range has only one column), what are you trying to achieve with `regexextract` in that place?

Comment: Maybe if I share the project things will become a little more clear https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z5km6kZnLwtn1ojy_3V75jWKysVlTMZyC6sl2Rnx9Hg/edit?usp=sharing F1:F10 > 4 is supposed to filter out any stocks that are below $4.00 and F:10 < 20 filters out any that are above $20. I actually have it set to F1:F:7036 > 4 and F1:F7036 < 20. Regextract in that place extracts numbers from the cells and feeds the data into the sort function which in turn ends up in column F.

Comment: I have an algorithm that trades stocks but really only reads full strings and not spreadsheets so the ultimate goal is output a string of stocks based on certain parameters/filters. The end result should end up looking like "AAPL, CFI, GELT, FTR, IAF, AGF, etc.". Those would be the stocks to trade since they meet the price and formula criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is to have a column with a list of `<Ticker>,<Price>` fields that is filtered for `<price> > 4` and `<price> < 20`, try this:

```
=filter(D:D,B:B>4,B:B<20)
```

This will return the corresponding `Ticker,Price` filtered by the price column.

Comment: Perfect, that worked exactly how I was wanting. Thanks so much!